# Jenkins build history for all jobs

Tags: jenkins, pipeline

I'am using Jenkins and I would like to have statistics of all builds executions.

I'am already using the plugin "build-metric" but pipeline jobs are not included in the statistics.

How to include pipeline jobs in the result of this plugin ? Or do you know an another plugin which include pipeline job ?

Comment: What type of statistics?  I could write you a script for the script console that does it.  That plugin hasnt been updated in 5 years and the screenshots are actually for Hudson.  Try a different metrics plugin altogether

Comment: The same statistics given by "build-metric" plugin : Number total of builds, Nb of success, nb of failed, etc...